# Validation loss lower than training loss but worse accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I am training a FFNN for classification and wonder why my validation loss always seems to be to low compared to training loss, as accuracy is also worse for validation than training.

I found some similar questions leading to the point that it's per se possible to have better performance in validation data set than in the training set, but not in the scenario of lower loss AND lower accuracy.

[image]

here's the code i use for training my pytorch NN including the loss calculation:

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model_pyt.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, betas=(0.9,0.999))
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    start_time = time.time()
    train_running_loss = 0
    train_acc = 0
    with torch.set_grad_enabled(True):
        for i, data_pack in enumerate(training_generator):
            x_data, y_data = data_pack 
            optimizer.zero_grad()                
            outputs = model_pyt(x_data)
            loss = criterion(outputs, y_data)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_running_loss += loss.detach().item()
            train_acc += get_accuracy(outputs, y_data, batch_size)
    test_labels = torch.tensor(labels_test).long()
    test_inputs = torch.tensor(np.array(data_bal_test)).float()
    test_outputs = model_pyt(test_inputs)
    test_loss = criterion(test_outputs, test_labels).detach().item()
    test_acc = get_accuracy(test_outputs, test_labels, len(test_labels))
    print('Epoch:  %d | Loss: %.4f | Acc %.4f | Test-Loss: %.4f | Test-Acc %.4f | Time Elapsed: %s' 
          %(epoch+1, train_running_loss/(i+1), train_acc/(i+1), loss, test_acc, time_since(start_time)))
    print('=====================================================================================================')
```

Comment: It's a bug: you do not print the test loss. You actually print `loss`, which is the loss over the last batch. 

Replace `loss` in the printing line with `test_loss`, and see what happens.

Comment: damnit! thank you, don't know how I could not see that...  
So this question might be considered unnecessary